# Html TextBox Array

Tags: c#, jquery, html, textbox

I have a list of textboxes as an array created using jQuery

```
<input type="text" name="salaries[]" value="100,000">
<input type="text" name="salaries[]" value="200,000">
<input type="text" name="salaries[]" value="300,000">
<input type="text" name="salaries[]" value="400,000">
```

Now in C# :

Request.Form["salaries[]"] gives
salaries[] = 100,000,200,000,300,000,400,000
Now I am unable to split the values as the commas get mixed up
How can this split be achieved?

Comment: cant you just remove the commas on the values you initially pass, then use String.Split

Comment: How can I remove the values before postback? any ideas??

Answer (score 3):

You can't fix it on the server, you have to fix the problem on the client first.

One method is to use unique names for each textbox. ie

```
<input type="text" name="salaries[0]" value="100,000">
<input type="text" name="salaries[1]" value="200,000">
<input type="text" name="salaries[2]" value="300,000">
<input type="text" name="salaries[3]" value="400,000">
```

And then (assuming you are using mvc??) the controller will be like this

```
public void save(String[] salaries) { ...
```

If not mvc, iterate over all parameters with a name starting with salaries